# Laravel lumen calling multiple authorization in contoller using gate

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I have Gate in `AuthServiceProvider` like this

```
//.......


Gate::define('parent', function($user){
    // parrent permission
});

Gate::define('child', function($user){
    // child permission
});


//.....
```

in some cases I want to call those authorizations and other case i just want to call the parent authorize. When I call just one authorize like this contoller below, It works.

```
// contoller A

// ........
$this->authorize('parent')

//.......
```

but how to call multiple authorize ?. I did this but it doesn't works.

```
// contoller B

// ........
$this->authorize('parent') || $this->authorize('child');

//.......

is there any other way to do that?
plese help. thanks!
```

Comment: Have you tried with `Gate::any`? Just use a if like `if (Gate::any(['parent', 'child'])) {}`

Comment: @johannchopin Let me try, thanks!.